# Check if a road is available in something similar to a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search-tree

I have a coordinates system which looks like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/tecdB.png Where the points -> (depthToNode, Node). But I don't have this structure, just raw points. You can go from (x,y) only to (x+1,y+1) or (x+1,y-1).

The data I get is a n < 500000, n - number of 'pillars' with blocked points. Then for each n I get x, a, b which are: x - the x coord of the pillar, a - everyone y coord <= a is blocked, b - everyone y coord >= b is blocked. The next x is always greater than the previous one. For Example: (x,a,b) -> (4,0,5). Then I know that the not blocked points on x = 4 are (4,2),(4,4). Note that if x is even then y must be also even, otherwise we can't go through such a point, for example (4,1), (4,3).

I noticed that if our coordinates are like (s,m) and I want to go to (c,d) then if c+d-s-m >= 0 then I can get from point (s,m) to (c,d). But the problem is that if I get 500000 'pillars' with blocked points, and the points are blocked from y < -10^8 and y > 10^8 then there is a large amount of points to check.

**So the question is: How can I check if I can go from point (0,0) to the one of the points (x,y) avoiding the points which are blocking the path. (x,y) are all the points not blocked in the last 'pillar'**

**EXAMPLE 1:**

**INPUT:**

4

1 0 2

4 -5 3

5 1 3

8 2 5

**OUTPUT: NO**

**EXAMPLE 2:**

**INPUT:**

4

1 0 2

4 3 5

5 -1000 3000

8 1 98

**OUTPUT: YES**

Comment: Clarification request: if `(x,a,b) → (4,0,5)` and only nodes with values _strictly_ less than `a` and _strictly_ greater than `b` are omitted, the remaining set of nodes shall be `(4,0); (4,2); (4,4)`. Is the inequality indeed strict? At which of the ends?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should be less or even than _a_ and greater or even than _b_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to check all possible nodes.

For each step of tree culling we only need to keep 2 values: min and max nodes that survived this step at its base level N. Let`s call them L<sub>N</sub> and U<sub>N</sub>, respectively.

Given the range [L<sub>N</sub>; U<sub>N</sub>] we can easily find [L<sub>N+K</sub>; U<sub>N+K</sub>] for any natural K.

Now we choose K so that N + K = N`, i.e. the level where the next step of culling is to be performed. We already know [L<sub>N`</sub>; U<sub>N`</sub>], see above. And now we compute [L`<sub>N`</sub>; U`<sub>N`</sub>] — the range of values that actually survived this next step at level N`.

Intersect these two ranges and repeat.

Proceed until either [L<sub>N`</sub>; U<sub>N`</sub>] ∩ [L`<sub>N`</sub>; U`<sub>N`</sub>] = ∅ (in which case the answer`s NO) or there is no more data left (the answer`s YES).

Illustration:

```
                         0
                     -1     1
                  -2     0     2
               -3    -1     1     3
            -4    -2     0     2     4
         -5    -3    -1     1     3     5
      -6    -4    -2     0     2     4     6
   -7    -5    -3    -1     1     3     5     7
-8    -6    -4    -2     0     2     4     6     8


                         0
                            1                       ←  #1 (1: 0, 2)
                         0     2
                     -1     1     3
                  -2_____0_____2_____4_
               -3    -1     1     3     5
            -4    -2     0     2     4     6
         -5    -3    -1     1     3     5     7
      -6    -4    -2     0     2     4     6     8


                         0
                            1                       ←  #1 (1: 0, 2)
                         0     2
                     -1     1     3
                                     4              ←  #2 (4: 3, 5)
                                 _3_____5_
                               2     4     6
                            1     3     5     7
                         0     2     4     6     8


                         0
                            1                       ←  #1 (1: 0, 2)
                         0     2
                     -1     1     3
                                     4              ←  #2 (4: 3, 5)
                                  3     5           ←  #3 (5: –1000, 3000)
                               2     4     6
                            1     3     5     7
                        _0_____2_____4_____6_____8_


                         0
                            1                       ←  #1 (1: 0, 2)
                         0     2
                     -1     1     3
                                     4              ←  #2 (4: 3, 5)
                                  3     5           ←  #3 (5: –1000, 3000)
                               2     4     6
                            1     3     5     7
                               2     4     6     8  ←  #4 (8: 1, 98)
```